# Chain complex and cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am trying to understant some ddetails from physical article.

In article there are two statements, which I wanna to understand.

1. We have complex $$
      \mathcal{C}_* = \mathbb{Z}[1]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[2]
      $$
   With differential operator:
   $$
      \Delta = \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1\\
      0&0
      \end{pmatrix}
      $$
   Cohomologies:
   $$
      H_*(\mathcal{C}_*, \Delta) \cong 0 
      $$

2. Second example: $$
      \Delta = \begin{pmatrix}
      0& 0 & 0 &1\\
      0& 0 & 0 &1\\
      0& 0 & 0 &1\\
      0&0 & 0 & 0
      \end{pmatrix}
      $$
   $$
      \mathcal{C}_* = \mathbb{Z}[1]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[1]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[1]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[2]
      $$
   $$
      H_*(\mathcal{C}_*, \Delta) \cong \mathbb{Z}[1] \oplus \mathbb{Z}[1] 
      $$

3. There is also third example:
   $$
      \Delta = \begin{pmatrix}
      0& 1 & 1 &0\\
      0& 0 & 0 &1\\
      0& 0 & 0 &1\\
      0&0 & 0 & 0
      \end{pmatrix}
      $$
   $$
      \mathcal{C}_* = \mathbb{Z}[0]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[1]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[1]\oplus \mathbb{Z}[2]
      $$
   $$
      H_*(\mathcal{C}_*, \Delta) \cong 0
      $$

I am not familar with such calculation. I will be very glad if somebody clarify such calculation and give me answer with all details .

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your notation right, the first complex is
$$\cdots\to 0\to\Bbb Z\stackrel{\phi}\to\Bbb Z\to0\to\cdots$$
where $\phi(a)=a$
and your second complex is
$$\cdots\to 0\to\Bbb Z^3\stackrel{\psi}\to\Bbb Z\to0\to\cdots$$
where $\psi(a,b,c)=a+b+c$.

I'll look at the second example. The cohomology at a position in the
sequences is the kernel of the map emerging by the image of the map entering.
Then $H^1(C^*)$ is the kernel of $\psi$, factored by the image of the zero
map, so really just the kernel of $\psi$. This is a free subgroup of $\Bbb Z^3$
generated by $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ so is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^2$.

Also $H^2(C^*)$ is the kernel of the zero map (so $\Bbb Z$),
factored by the image $\psi$. But $\psi$ is surjective, so $\psi$ has image $\Bbb Z$
and so $H^2(C^*)$ vanishes.

Comment: Thank you! I added third example, could you extend you calculation to this example? I didn't understand, how construct map from  $\Delta$..

Comment: @Nikita I take a dim view of such requests. But I don't think your third example is a complex, since $\Delta^2$ is nonzero.